# What should be the right model to analyse this data? Should I use time series analysis?

Tags: regression, time-series, predictive-models

I got a biomanufacturing dataset and try to build a model for the crystallization part. There are two variables: the temperature (T) of the tank (which is changing over time but specified by the operator) and the average length (L) of the crystals.
[image]

I am not sure what model should I use to model the trend in crystal length. I am thinking of using ARMAX model, but I read some tutorials and it seems that time series analysis is only used to model stationary series. However, it is clearly observed from the plot that both T and L are non-stationary. But if I do differentiation, I am not sure if the model is useful or not because I can see clearly there is a relationship between L and T and the cyclic behavior of L is caused by T.

I am new to time series analysis, and I always have a question: if the series is differentiated to make it stationary, for the future testing data, it has to be differentiated first and then makes the prediction?

And for this particular problem, what is the correct model to get L=f(T) or L=f(T,L(t-1))?

Thanks!

Comment: regARIMA or ARIMAX is an option, as your process seems to be non stationary

Comment: Would you please post a link to the raw data used for the graph?

Comment: @Aksakai Hi thanks for your reply! I might be wrong but for ARIMAX model isn't that requires the x and y to be stationary time series?